# Syncing two folders between two Linux workstations (Two different networks)

Tags: command-line

I have two Linux work stations:

```
Workstation A at home
Workstation B at work
```

The workstations are linked to the internet and they don't belong to the same network.

How can I sync a folder "Test" between Workstation A and B, Although, they don't belong to the same network:

I tried:

```
rsync -avu -e ssh /Test/ server@X.X.X.X:/Path/to/Test
```

This command keep output an error message "No route to host"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Usually, workplaces frown upon ssh connection coming in or going out from/to servers outside the corporate networks. When you are at work, try making an `ssh` connection to your server A (at home) and see if it succeeds, before getting to the `rsync` part

Comment: @MelBurslan. Thanks! I tried and the output also " "No route to host""

Comment: There lies your problem. Ask your network administrators (or firewall admins) what kind of restrictions were put on outgoing ssh connections. There might be a static route (means they log everything that goes through) that you might need to add so that you can ssh to home from work. If they say "No, it is not allowed and totally blocked" unfortunately you are out of luck.

Comment: Is the X.X.X.X you're using your home machine's *internal* IP address? E.g., one that starts with 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x, or 172.16–31.x.x?

Comment: @derobert. Yes!

Comment: @goro that's your problem—you need to set up a port-forward in your router to allow external access to your workstation at home, then use your router's public IP address. Unless your home router is a Unix/Linux box, how to do that is probably off-topic here…